# How stable is NSubstitute?

Tags: unit-testing, nsubstitute

My company is looking to standardize on an Isolation Framework.  I was looking at [MS Stubs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/stubs/) (cause Moles seemed cool and I thought I would keep it in the same framework).  However, Stubs is not quite ready for prime time yet (it is still a bit [buggy in normal functionality](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/thread/c9b8ce14-b9e5-4d1c-a021-4abc6dc02936)).

So now I am looking at what else is out there.  I have looked at Moq and Rhino mocks.  While doing that, I came across the fabulous [comparisons done by Richard Banks](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/mocking-comparison-part-1-basics.html).  In that he shows [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/). I really like what I see there.

However, after having been burned a bit by MS Stubs, I don't want to bet on an alpha/non-production ready Isolation Framework.

So, is NSubstitute ready for prime time?  Or is it still a bit buggy?

Comment: I also just discovered NSubstitute from the Richard Banks article, and for a rusty old programmer like myself, NSubstitute is a God-send!  After messing about with Rhino Mocks for ages, NSubstitute just works.  Hooray for well-designed software!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a [discussion about this](http://groups.google.com/group/nsubstitute/browse_thread/thread/75c6b686dc45a879) on the official NSubstitute group.

The alpha tag was originally used to indicate that the API was still subject to change. The API has now stabilised, and most of the outstanding work for a 1.0 release is documentation. You can get an indication of some other planned work (for both v1 and v2; mostly planned features) from the [issue log](http://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues).

We have been using NSubstitute on a major project with a team of 6 developers and are very happy with it.

*Note: I work on NSubstitute, so may be a tad biased. :)*

**UPDATE:** [NSubstitute 1.0 has been released](http://groups.google.com/group/nsubstitute/browse_thread/thread/23349697b1d9e252).

Comment: Sweet!  I am very happy to hear that it is in beta now.  I am going to be training my company on unit testing next week, so having it exit alpha now is perfect timing!

Answer (score 9):

I've been using NSubstitute on my [project](http://github.com/sinesignal/ottoman/tree/development/src/SineSignal.Ottoman.Specs/) and I haven't had any problems.  I picked NSubstitue mainly just to try it out, because I like the syntax and how easy it is to fake an implementation due to it being loose.  Since I wasn't sure if I would keep using it at the time, I put a little wrapper around it for my own little DSL, whenever I need a fake.

Also to note, I mainly develop C# on Linux with Ubuntu, Mono, and MonoDevelop and I haven't had any problems with it working under the Mono 2.6.7 runtime.  You can probably use any of the 2.6.* runtimes, but I haven't tried it.  The Mono 2.6.* runtime is equivalent to the .NET 3.5 Framework.

It's everything they were hoping, with their phrase from the website:  It's meant to be simple, succinct and pleasant to use.

Comment: Thank you for your input on how well it works with your projects.

Answer (score 7):

We were using Rhino Mocks but we have replaced all our mocking code with NSubstitute. It is very stable, far easier to work with, away less code required to do what you have got to do and a small, concise but effective API.

Would strongly recommend it!